# Create pandas subtraction column based on one other column in two conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with subjects in two different conditions and many value columns.

```
d = {
     "subject": [1, 1, 2, 2], 
     "condition": ["on", "off", "on", "off"], 
     "value": [1, 2, 3, 5]
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

|  | subject | condition | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | on | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | off | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | on | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | off | 5 |

I would like to get new columns which indicate the difference *off-on* between both conditions. In this case I would like to get:

|  | subject | condition | value | off-on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | on | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | off | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | on | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | off | 5 | 2 |

How would I best do that?

I could achieve the result using this code:

```
onoff = (df[df.condition == "off"].value.reset_index() - df[df.condition == "on"].value.reset_index()).value
for idx, sub in enumerate(df.subject.unique()):
    df.loc[df.subject == sub, "off-on"] = onoff.iloc[idx]
```

But it seems quite tedious and slow. I was hoping for a solution without loop. I have many rows and very many value columns. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) combined with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['off-on'] = df['subject'].map(
 df.pivot(index='subject', columns='condition', values='value')
   .eval('off-on')
)
```

Or with a MultiIndex (more efficient than a `pivot`):

```
s = df.set_index(['condition', 'subject'])['value']
df['off-on'] = df['subject'].map(s['off']-s['on'])
```

Output:

```
   subject condition  value  off-on
0        1        on      1       1
1        1       off      2       1
2        2        on      3       2
3        2       off      5       2
```

###### timings

On 100k subjects

```
# MultiIndexing
43.2 ms ± 2.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# pivot
77 ms ± 12.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for your great solutions @mozway! Unfortunately, I realized I need something more sophisticated. [Here is the new version of my question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75300179/create-pandas-subtraction-column-based-on-one-other-column-and-multiindex)

Comment: @Moritz I provided an answer there

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for possible easy mapping subtracted column `off` and `on` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='subject', columns='condition', values='value')

df['off-on'] = df['subject'].map(df1['off'].sub(df1['on']))
print (df)
   subject condition  value  off-on
0        1        on      1       1
1        1       off      2       1
2        2        on      3       2
3        2       off      5       2
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.pivot(index='subject', columns='condition', values='value'))
condition  off  on
subject           
1            2   1
2            5   3

print (df1['off'].sub(df1['on']))
subject
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your great solution @jezrael! Unfortunately, I realized I need something more sophisticated. [Here is the new version of my question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75300179/create-pandas-subtraction-column-based-on-one-other-column-and-multiindex)