# Create pandas subtraction column based on one other column and multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have asked a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75296138/create-pandas-subtraction-column-based-on-one-other-column-in-two-conditions/75296162#75296162), unfortunately, the toy problem is too simple for my case.

I have a dataframe with subjects in two different conditions and many value columns for various channels.

```
d = {
     "subject": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
     "condition": ["on", "off", "on", "off", "on", "off"], 
     "channel": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
     "value": [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6]
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

|  | subject | condition | channel | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | on | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | off | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | on | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | off | 1 | 6 |
| 4 | 3 | on | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 3 | off | 2 | 6 |

I would like to get new columns which indicate the difference *off-on* between both conditions *for each channel*. If one channel is missing in one condition, I would like to get nan. In this case I would like to get:

|  | subject | condition | channel | value | value_off-on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | on | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | off | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | on | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | off | 1 | 6 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 | on | 1 | 4 | nan |
| 5 | 3 | off | 2 | 6 | nan |

How would I best do that?

I have to tried to extend the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75296138/create-pandas-subtraction-column-based-on-one-other-column-in-two-conditions/75296162#75296162), however, this throws errors:

```
df['off-on'] = df.set_index(['subject', 'channel']).map(
 df.pivot(index=['subject', 'channel'], columns='condition', values='value')
   .eval('off-on')
)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

```
s = df.set_index(['condition', 'subject', 'channel'])['value']
df['off-on'] = df[['subject', 'channel']].map(s['off']-s['on'])
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

What's the solution?

Comment: can there be multiple on and off for each subject?

Comment: @NehalBirla, Yes, but only if there are multiple channels for each subject! There can be exactly one on and one off for each subject and each channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your existing solution with `MultiIndex.map`

```
s = df.pivot(index=['subject', 'channel'], columns='condition', values='value').eval('off-on')
df['off-on'] = df.set_index(['subject', 'channel']).index.map(s)
```

Alternatively you can use `merge`:

```
s = df.pivot(index=['subject', 'channel'], columns='condition', values='value').eval('off-on')
df.merge(s.reset_index(name='off-on'))
```

Result

```
   subject condition  channel  value  off-on
0        1        on        1      1     1.0
1        1       off        1      2     1.0
2        2        on        1      3     3.0
3        2       off        1      6     3.0
4        3        on        1      4     NaN
5        3       off        2      6     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['value_off-on'] = (df.groupby(['subject', 'channel'])['value']
                        .transform(lambda x: x.diff().iloc[-1]))
print(df)

# Output
   subject condition  channel  value  value_off-on
0        1        on        1      1           1.0
1        1       off        1      2           1.0
2        2        on        1      3           3.0
3        2       off        1      6           3.0
4        3        on        1      4           NaN
5        3       off        2      6           NaN
```

Note: If your dataframe is not already sorted by `condition`, you have to sort it before with `df.sort_values('condition', ascending=False).groupby(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Modification of [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75296162/16343464) to work with multiple columns:

```
s = df.set_index(['condition', 'subject', 'channel'])['value']

# instead of map, use a merge
df['off-on'] = (df[['subject', 'channel']]
                .merge(s['off'].sub(s['on']).reset_index(), how='left')
               )['value']

# or indexing
df['off-on'] = df.set_index(['subject', 'channel']).index.map(s['off'].sub(s['on']))
```

Output:

```
   subject condition  channel  value  off-on
0        1        on        1      1     1.0
1        1       off        1      2     1.0
2        2        on        1      3     2.0
3        2       off        1      5     2.0
4        3        on        1      4     NaN
5        3       off        2      6     NaN
```